# How to create toggle combination for instruction stepping mode in Eclipse debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

It's possible to create keyboard shortcut for custom action in eclipse by [extension point](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F). 
I tried to create in plugin own shortcut for toggle in debug the instruction stepping mode in Eclipse (ver. Oxygen.2, release 4.7.2) by adding this code in plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key sequence="Shift+I"
        commandId="org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.ui.actions.ToggleInstructionStepModeActionDelegate"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope"/>
</extension>
```

Toggle to this mode provides [ToggleInstructionStepModeActionDelegate](https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/master/debug/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/debug/internal/ui/actions/ToggleInstructionStepModeActionDelegate.java). But in debug my shortcut does not work. What should I fix or add?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `commandId` must be the id of a command declarated using  the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point -does Eclipse CDT declare that command id? (I don't use it so I don't know). You have also declared the binding to be in the 'text editor' context which is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: You're right, it does not declare that command id. But I have found I can create custom command by creating the handler. I will checkout context and post solution If I can do it right :)